# what is the best solution to create a black list of products?

Tags: commerce

I'm implementing a site with drupal commerce and the customer needs to have a black list of some products. for example when a product get out of stock and they don't supply it anymore, they want to add that product to black list, only by entering the name of product in a text box. what is the best solution to implement such a thing since they don't want to handle it by a field (e.g a checkbox) in the time of creating a node.

Comment: Why not just get them to change the product status to disabled? That'll stop it being displayed/purchased. Then you can build a simple view to show all disabled products - your blacklist

Comment: because they fetch the products via webservices from another website.